# Group numbers into least number of buckets of size X

Tags: javascript, arrays

Looking for examples on how to group a collection of numbers into the least number of buckets of size X.

For example, if I have this array of numbers:

```
var myCompartments = { 4, 6, 2, 8, 6, 3, 1, 1, 4, 2, 7, 2, 8, 3, 9 };
```

and I want to group them into buckets using this bucket size:

```
var bucketSize = 12;
```

What I am looking for is a function or algorithm that will group these into the least number of buckets matching the bucketSize and then will give me the remaining numbers (that didn't fit) in a list of its own.

Sample results I'd like to see:

```
var buckets = [ 
    { 4, 6, 2 },
    { 8, 3, 1 },
    { 6, 4, 2 },
    { 9, 3 }
];

var leftovers = {1, 7, 2, 8 };
```

If it could output similar to the sample results that would be great. The least number of items that are in the "left over" list, the better.

What I have so far is simply just looping through the collection and adding to a bucket if there is room, and creating a new bucket if there isn't. This is inefficient and ends up with a lot of partially full buckets. I'm using angularJS, so there are a few shortcut methods used here:

```
var bucketSize = 12;
var buckets = [
    { remainingCapacity: bucketSize, items: [] }
];
var myCompartments = [
    { isAssigned: false, size: 4 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 6 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 2 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 8 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 6 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 3 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 1 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 1 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 4 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 2 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 7 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 2 },   
    { isAssigned: false, size: 8 },
    { isAssigned: false, size: 3 },
    { isAssigned: false, size: 9 }
];

myCompartments.forEach(function(compartment) {
    buckets.forEach(function(bucket) {
        if (bucket.remainingCapacity >= compartment.size && !compartment.isAssigned) {
            bucket.remainingCapacity -= compartment.size;
            compartment.isAssigned = true;
            bucket.items.push(compartment);
        }
    });

    // if compartment still not assigned, add to a new bucket
    if (!compartment.isAssigned && bucketSize >= compartment.size) {
        compartment.isAssigned = true;
        var remainingCapacity = bucketSize - compartment.size;
        var newBucket = { remainingCapacity: remainingCapacity, items: [] };
        newBucket.items.push(compartment);
        buckets.push(newBucket);
    }
});
```

Edit - I've created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9SSdv0QWZqcmuejubAfg?p=preview) that outputs the created buckets for debugging

Comment: and what have you done so far?

Comment: Nina i've added my code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't pretty but it works.

It loops through the data multiple times, each time shuffling the array values in attempt to find a better order for grouping items into buckets of specific size.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UI4tTq0Y35jSHvnTYWUr?p=preview)

```
$(function() {

  var bucketSize = 12;  
  var buckets = [{
    remainingCapacity: bucketSize,
    pieces: []
  }];

  var pieces = [
      { isAssigned: false, size: 4 },     
      { isAssigned: false, size: 6 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 2 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 8 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 6 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 3 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 1 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 1 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 4 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 2 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 7 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 2 },   
      { isAssigned: false, size: 8 },
      { isAssigned: false, size: 3 },
      { isAssigned: false, size: 9 }
  ];

  var unassignedCount = pieces.length;

  var count = 1000;

  while (count--) {

    shuffle(pieces);  

    var p = pieces.length;
    var b = 0;

    while (p--) {

      var piece = pieces[p];
      b = buckets.length;

      while (b--) {

        var bucket = buckets[b];

        // add to bucket if there is room and piece is not assigned
        if (bucket.remainingCapacity >= piece.size && !piece.isAssigned) {
          bucket.remainingCapacity -= piece.size;
          piece.isAssigned = true;
          bucket.pieces.push(piece);
        }
      }

      // if not assigned and not bigger than bucketSize, add to new bucket
      if (!piece.isAssigned && piece.size <= bucketSize) {
        var remainingCapacity = bucketSize - piece.size;
        var newBucket = {
          remainingCapacity: remainingCapacity,
          pieces: []
        };
        newBucket.pieces.push(piece);
        buckets.push(newBucket);
      }

      pieces.splice(p, 1);

    }

    b = buckets.length;

    while (b--) {
      var bucket = buckets[b];
      if (bucket.remainingCapacity > 0) {
        p = bucket.pieces.length;
        while (p--) {
          var piece = bucket.pieces[p];
          piece.isAssigned = false;
          pieces.push(piece);
          bucket.pieces.splice(p, 1);
        }
        buckets.splice(b, 1);
      }

    }  

    unassignedCount = pieces.length;

  }


  function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length,
      temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    // While there remain elements to shuffle...
    while (0 !== currentIndex) {

      // Pick a remaining element...
      randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
      currentIndex -= 1;

      // And swap it with the current element.
      temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
      array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
      array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
  }

  document.write('number of buckets: ' + buckets.length + '<br><br>');
  document.write('number of remaining pieces: ' + unassignedCount + '<br>    <br>');
  buckets.forEach(function(bucket) {
    document.write('bucket:<br>');
    document.write('remaining capacity: ' + bucket.remainingCapacity + '<br>');
    document.write('items:<br>');
    bucket.pieces.forEach(function(piece) {
      document.write('size: ' + piece.size + '<br>');
    });
    document.write('<br>');
  });

  document.write('<br>leftovers: ');
  pieces.forEach(function(piece) {
    if (!piece.isAssigned) {
      document.write(piece.size + ', ');
    }
  });

});
```

if anyone else has a more elegant solution I would be very interested to see what you come up with! thanks.